# Does using " + " operator converts to higher datatype for lists in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

While solving a quiz question in a Coursera course i encountered the below question.

What will be the output of the below code -

```
print(['a','b','c','d']+[1,2,3,4])
```

and the correct answer was

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I am a little confused why did this work since the below code fails

```
print('a'+1)
```

giving the below error, due to mismatch in type string + integer

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Thanks.

Comment: list + list is the same type. str + int is not the same type.

Comment: What would you expect for the second one?  '+' is defined between lists, but not between a string and an integer.  This is covered in the documentation and tutorials.

Comment: You are concatenating lists, not strings and numbers.

Comment: It is just a design decision for the language.

Comment: At which point do you suspect a conversion to a higher data type?

Comment: As others have explained this is how Python calls `extends` method underneath `+` operator for list. To further clear out the statement try executing this `(1,2) + [2,4]` which should give an error

Comment: @mad_ no, it does not. Rather, *augmented* assignment is equivalent to `.extend`, so `x += y` when `x` is a `list` you'll see that `y` can be any iterable, just like `x.extend(y)`, however, `x + y` requires both the left and right operands to be list objects. Furthermore, the concatenation operator *creates a new list*. `.extend` mutates the list in-place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two examples are inherently different. Inside the print statement:

In the first snippet, you're typing `['a'] + [1]` which adds two lists (same type) and gives another list as output

In the second snippet, you're typing `'a' + 1`, which tries to add an int to a string (two different types), so you get a `TypeError`.

Hope this helps!

---

Edit, since this has been marked as the accepted answer: For more detailed information, see [the Python Data Model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) and [how to implement __add__](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#implementing-the-arithmetic-operations).

Comment: It is not the point if data types are same or different but if the operation is defined for the types or not. Example: `3 + 0.5` works but `None + None` doesn't.

Comment: @MichaelButscher you're right, but that this is too complicated for the person asking the question. Based on the question, I got a sense of his experience level, and did my best to answer the question in a way that matches his ability. But you're right; I could have been more in-depth in my answer. For anyone who's curious as to how it really works:

Comment: Adding two objects calls the `__add__(self, other)` method of the first object (implemented in the parent class). When you call `"some string" + int(1)`, it basically runs `"some string".__add__(self, 1)`, which the class has hopefully overloaded for this specific `other` object. If there's a mismatch (e.g. the \_\_add\_\_ method of str returns NotImplemented for any other object that's not a string) it can raise a TypeError, AttributeError, or other exception. Side note: NoneType doesn't implement anything, which is why `None + None`, or for that matter `None + anything`, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have answered your question: in the first example, you concatenate two objects of the same type (a list and a list). In the second example, you try to concatenate two objects with different types (str and int) which is not possible.

Comment: It is not the point if data types are same or different but if the operation is defined for the types or not. Example: `3 + 0.5` works but `None + None` doesn't.